# mysql - how to join two tables and only add values from the second table if there are nulls in the first table?

Tags: mysql

table A that has X and Y fields. some Y fields are blank. table B has X and Z fields. how do I join A and B such that only the blank Y fields get populated with Z values and none of the existing Y fields are overwritten without making a new table and unioning it?

```
A
X1    Y1
X2    
X3    Y2

B
X1    Z1
X2    Z2
X3

A join B
X1    Y1
X2    Z2
X3    Y2
```

Comment: Are they `NULL` or are they empty strings? They're not the same thing.

Comment: 40 columns *might* be symptomatic of poor schema design

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this to display data from table `b` if table `a` is missing some info like so:

```
select a.f1, coalesce(a.f2, b.f2) as f2 from a left join b on a.f1 = b.f1;
+------+------+
| f1   | f2   |
+------+------+
| X1   | Y1   |
| X2   | Z2   |
| X3   | Y2   |
+------+------+
```

Note that this will **not** change your table. It'll just output information as you desire.

If you want to actually update table `a` and populate missing values with those from table `b`, you can do something like this:

```
update a inner join b on a.f1 = b.f1
set a.f2 = b.f2
where a.f2 is null and b.f2 is not null;
```

Then, your table `a` will look like this:

```
select * from a;
+------+------+
| f1   | f2   |
+------+------+
| X1   | Y1   |
| X2   | Z2   |
| X3   | Y2   |
+------+------+
```

Example tables I used are:

```
create table a (f1 char(2), f2 char(2));
create table b (f1 char(2), f2 char(2));
insert into a values ('X1', 'Y1'), ('X2', null), ('X3', 'Y2');
insert into b values ('X1', 'Z1'), ('X2', 'Z2'), ('X3', null);
```

Comment: so my table has 40 columns. is there any way to select the coalesce statement and the rest of a without f2 without listing every column?

Comment: @xaxado2791 I might ask a series of questions to understand your particular use case better. So bear with me for a moment. Does table `a` and table `b` has 40 columns? Or does only one of the table have 40 columns? If only one table has 40 columns, which table has 40 columns? Do you want only column `f2`'s missing data populated or do you want all other 38 column's missing data populated also?

Answer (score 0):

You could do two different `SELECT` statements with a `UNION`.

```
SELECT v1, v2 FROM A WHERE v2 is NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT B.v1, B.v2 FROM A, B 
  WHERE B.v1 = A.v1 
  AND A.v2 IS NULL
  AND B.v2 IS NOT NULL
```

The first one takes care of the primary case where the value exists in `A`.  The second takes care of when the value is not in `A`, but is in `B`.

This does use a `UNION` but does not create a new table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65c497/2